# How to install a Canon PIXMA MG3520 Wireless printer

Tags: printing, canon, pixma

I recently purchased a Canon PIXMA MG3520 Wireless all in one printer. I have tried every way, to install it. How to install this printer?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to do some changes (might be the first step of the procedure in installation because this it the folder where you download the file) to make it work for you because the steps he posted are for ubuntu users.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209879

This is what he posted:

Re: Trouble installing Canon Pixma MG3500 printer driver

So if one was starting from the beginning, I would suggest going to the Canon Asia [site](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/?personal) and finding the MG3500 [page](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/InkJet/PIXMA_iP_series/PIXMA_iP3500.aspx?type=download&language=&os=Linux) and what you would download would be `iP3500_debian.tar`.

The commands to install it if the `Downloads` directory is where you download things to would be:

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf iP3500_debian.tar
cd iP3500_debian
sudo ./install.sh
```

and that should install it for you.